# How do I post a welcome message when my discord bot joins a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am new to JavaScript and I have made a small discord bot but I cannot find a way to make it have a welcome message when it joins the server. I want it to say something like "Hello my name is `{bot-name}`, type !help to view my commands." Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) event that is emitted whenever the bot joins a guild. You need to find a channel though where you can post your message.

To find a channel you can use the `.find()` method that returns the first channel where the given function returns a truthy value.

```js
client.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  const channelNames = ['general', 'welcome']
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.find(ch => channelNames.includes(ch.name))

  if (channel)
    channel.send(
      `Hello my name is ${client.user.username}, type \`!help\` to view my commands.`
    )
    .catch(console.error);
})
```