# How to Introduce the Bot [On added to server]

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a question regarding on how to detect if my discord bot was added to a server. I want to display an embed when they are added, an example would be: [image]

Can someone tell me how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js First Time Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609757/discord-js-first-time-message) or this? [How do I post a welcome message when my discord bot joins a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833818/how-do-i-post-a-welcome-message-when-my-discord-bot-joins-a-server/66834000#66834000)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```js
<Client>.on('guildCreate') event.
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate

Answer (score 0):

It's simple

I suppose you want to send a message in the guild when the bot is added

```js
client.on("guildCreate", async (guild) =>{
    guild.systemChannel.send({content: `Thank's for adding me into your server`})
})
```